# how to select rows that contains one or more keywords(from an existing list) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to select every row of a `pandas.DataFrame` which `df['Title']` has one(or more) of the `keywords` elements.

consider this list as keywords:
`keywords = ['k_1', 'k_2', 'k_3', 'k_4']`

I've tried this approach which did not worked out for me:
`df[df['Title'].str.contains(keywords)]`

Comment: You mean `df[df['Title'].isin(keywords)]`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM `Title = 'k_1 lorem ipsum bla bla'`, I want this to return `True`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
df[df["Title"].apply(lambda x: any(k in x for k in keywords))]
```

Comment: your approach is very neat, but in order to get the rows I had to wrap your code around brackets of `df`(I don't know the expression of doing such thing). so the answer I wanted is: `df[df["Title"].apply(lambda x: any(k in x for k in keywords))]`. Thank you

Comment: Yes ofc, this gives you all indexes you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a regex pattern and use `str.findall`:

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['k_1 and k_2', 'k_3 alone', 'k_z not here']})
keywords = ['k_1', 'k_2', 'k_3', 'k_4']
pattern = fr"\b({'|'.join(keywords)})\b"

df['Keywords'] = df['Title'].str.findall(pattern)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
          Title    Keywords
0   k_1 and k_2  [k_1, k_2]
1     k_3 alone       [k_3]
2  k_z not here          []

>>> print(pattern)
\b(k_1|k_2|k_3|k_4)\b
```

Get rows:

```
>>> df[df['Title'].str.findall(pattern).astype(bool)]
         Title
0  k_1 and k_2
1    k_3 alone
```

Comment: very robust solution, thank you; but I'm afraid I needed a simpler way.

Comment: Not a problem. Maybe the answer of @thomask is the right. Why do you think it's a complicated solution?

Comment: yes hopefully @thomask was was much cleaner and easier to understand. but I think yours is more powerful and customizable.